# Can any of the monsters break glass?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tend to build my house nearly completely out of glass because I like to be able to see all nearby threats. Are there any monsters with the ability to break glass? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 20):

Glass is a fragile block when compared to other ones. Looking at [this page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_resistance) on the Minecraft Wiki which lists every block and their resistances to explosions, Glass blocks have a blast resistance rating of 1.5. There are two mobs in the game which either explode or shoot projectiles that explode: the [Creeper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper) and the [Ghast](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ghast). In order to not be broken by a Ghast's fireballs, a block must have a resistance rating of 20.17 or higher, and a Creeper's explosion is even more powerful than that. Because of this, you have to be careful to not let Creepers explode near or Ghasts shoot at your glass structures.

The other two destructive mob in Minecraft are the [Enderman](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman) and [Silverfish](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Silverfish). Endermen can pick up certain blocks and place them down elsewhere, but Glass is not one of the blocks they can pick up. Silverfish can hide in Stone, Cobblestone, and Stone Brick blocks which get destroyed when they appear from them, so they have no effect on Glass.

Comment: And since silverfish only exist in strongholds (unless manually moved), they aren't usually a danger to your house either.

Answer (score 12):

As an additional note to Kevin's response, while ghasts can break glass, according to the wiki they don't have much reason to:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ghast

and

> Ghasts will not fire at the player without a line-of-sight - this can be blocked by glass, glass panes, leaves, Nether portals, vines, iron bars, both types of fences, and cobwebs - making safe scenic paths through the Nether a viable possibility.

equally, this page https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creeper has a lovely discussion towards the bottom about creepers and buildings. The salient details? glad you asked!

> Since wooden slabs are a damage value of stone, They can be used to make wooden creeper-resistant houses.This no longer works as of 12w17a.
>
> Glass walls around entrances can preempt the creepers' habit of hiding in ambush around corners (but this is offset by the disadvantage that glass is not very durable in an explosion).
>
> Placing a small glass wall 2 or 3 blocks high around the area wanted to be protected can be a very effective method. Just don't get within the area where your wall is and keep the area being enclosed well lit.

(the above is because, apparently, creepers only explode when they're near you, not when they're blocked by walls)

> Fencing provides a great way to protect holdings, provided that the player finds fencing aesthetically compatible with a given property.

finally

> A ring of cats around a fortress will keep creepers at a safe distance at all times. While somewhat time-intensive, this is the most effective way at dealing with creepers, although other monsters can still draw close to your base at night.

Comment: You also have to put up with the constant meowling of cats all around you.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same question, so I did a test. I made a glass box, and stayed in it over night. I saw a zombie, who didn't seem to notice me, so I broke the glass and walked over to get his attention, then ran back into the glass box and put new glass in the holes I had made to seal myself in. The zombie then acted as if he couldnt even see me.

A few minutes later I saw a creeper and ran out to get his attention, then ran back and sealed myself in the box at the last second, and he immediately de-aggroed me and simply walked away.

I did this all on Hard difficulty survival mode. I wanted to know the question, so I could build a box to be safe in and AFK while my crops grew in my huge farm tower!!

Answer (score -1):

Well so far no. Zombies have tried to break in my house so along with other creatures but they haven't been able to break my windows... And I'm not on creative mode EVER! I play survival mode.

Comment: Hi Krissy, welcome to the site. This isn't really an answer, more of a discussion, which is not the way this site works. Once you've earned a bit more rep, come and hang out in chat if you want to discuss your favourite games!

Answer (score -1):

No monsters break glass, with the exception of creeper explosions.

Answer (score -1):

No Mobs can break glass with the exception of creeper blasts. I would recommend putting a fence around your house and torching up the fence so that creeper explosions can't affect your house.

Answer (score -2):

No zombies and other creatures can't break glass.
I make my house out of glass too!

Comment: Sources, references?